# PAW: Replace timestamp in json results with date time

Tags: paw-app

Is it possible to hint PAW that the integer value in result is timestamp and replace it with datetime automatically?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Unfortunately, not. Though, Paw can format Date times at request send, if that ever helps: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/dynamic-values/utils (last entry). I love the idea of "hints" for response values.

Comment: Would be nice to have