# PAW: Replace timestamp from response with date time Or any API for that?

Tags: paw-app

Still not have any idea for convert integer value to date time string in PAW?

Like 1574320970183 to "Thu Nov 21 2019 16:22:50 GMT+0900"

Or is there an API for replace that?

[same question has no anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504211/paw-replace-timestamp-in-json-results-with-date-time)